# you will/would be more likely to be kicked out from work

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

When you are predicting *probability* in the future, will+likeliness(less likely, more likely, most likely, etc.)

Do you use present tense(**are, is**) or future tense(**will**), or **would**

> Example: A teacher is giving advice to a lazy student:
>
> ''You can't do that in first world countries, because if you do, you **will/are/would** be *more likely* be kicked out from your job.''

Usually we see **more likely** in sentences with **is/are**(e.g children are more likely to be with their playmates than their parents) BUT what about **will** and **Would**? are they grammatical to use?

Comment: *....more likely to get kicked out....*

Comment: To be clear, all variations are fine. The tense used is entirely up to you.

Comment: @MaulikV, that's not a correction, your suggestion is another register, which is an informal way of saying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say:

> You can't do that in first world countries. If you do, you would/will/are likely (to) be kicked out of your job.

NOTE: The 'to' in brackets would only be necessary if you use 'you are likely'. It is not needed for either 'you would likely' or 'you will likely'.

You should only use "more likely" if you are comparing two things: e.g.

> You are more likely to be kicked out of your job for that sort of behaviour in first world countries (than second world countries).

The phrase in brackets could be omitted in certain situations, however, its presence would still be assumed. The omission would depend on the context in which the sentence is used. For example, in a conversation comparing norms in first and second world countries, the phrase might be omitted.

Comment: "**Incidentally, as nouns, Third World and First World are usually capitalized with no hyphen. As adjectives, they are uncapitalized and hyphenated.** "  http://grammarist.com/usage/first-world-third-world/

Comment: @RonaldSole, so it's going to be first-world countries right? Nice, thx!